# Issue with installing Flask-Migrate

Tags: python, pip

I have been trying to get Flask-Migrate to install it just doesn't want to work. Someone help me out please. I have tried to uninstall pip but that still doesnt work for me. I really dont understand what im doing wrong.

```
python3 -m pip install Flask-Migrate

Collecting Flask-Migrate
  Using cached Flask_Migrate-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy>=1.0
  Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.9 in /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages (from Flask-Migrate) (1.1.1)
Collecting alembic>=0.7
  Using cached alembic-1.4.2.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 331, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 516, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req, self.req_tracker, self.finder, self.build_isolation,
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 95, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 38, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._setup_isolation(finder)
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 96, in _setup_isolation
    reqs = backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 152, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    'config_settings': config_settings
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 255, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sai/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 63, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Comment: Not sure what instructions you're following, but installing into a virtual environment (either by `virtualenv -p python3 venv` or (depending on your python3 version) `python3 -m venv venv`) and the installing into that might be a lot easier.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith yeah thats what I ended up doing afterwards. Thanks for the suggestion!